# Sequence Generation to expire on JSP page refresh

Tags: java, sql, jsp

On Registering a new User in JSP, PID is generated automatically by sequence generator(SQL). But the problem occurs is when i refresh the submitted page save.jsp again, the same data is stored again with next value of sequence. How to avoid it?

## save.jsp

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 1); //prevents caching at the proxy server

String account = request.getParameter("account");
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
String notes = request.getParameter("notes");

String LoginUser=(String)session.getAttribute("uid");
passwords a = new passwords();

a.setLoginUser(LoginUser);
a.setAccount(account);
a.setUsername(username);
a.setPassword(password);
a.setNotes(notes);


SessionFactory sf = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session s = sf.openSession();
Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
s.save(a);
tx.commit();
```

### passwords.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "passwords")
public class passwords implements Serializable{

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "B", sequenceName = "PIDSeq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "B", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
int PID;
String LoginUser;
String username;
String account;
String password;
String notes;'
```

Comment: How about [POST-redirect-GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)?

Comment: @Crozin Can you please tell me in detail?

Answer (score 0):

When refreshing a page the brwoser always sends the last request, so after the first `POST` the next refresh will send the same `POST` request.

You need to implement the `POST/redirect/GET paradigm`:

After you handle `POST` request, do not write the response /serve the next resource directtly to the client, instead let the client perform a `GET` request to the next resource. This is done in a jsp or a servlet by calling [HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)). This way a refresh will always fire a `GET` request which is fine.